# jquery-ui dialog, how to apply css on the outmost div on the dialog window only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com) to create a dialog window. the div to be shown on the dialog has the class 'dialog'.

Let us look at the html first :

```
<div class="click_me">
Click Me
</div><!-- end of class click_me-->


<div class="dialog">

this is my dialog

</div>
```

css and javascript follow:

```
<style type="text/css">

.click_me{
    width:120px;
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;

    }


.dialog{

    width:230px;
    border:1px solid green;
    text-align:center;


    }   

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".click_me").click(function(){

    dialog_my=  $(".dialog").clone(false);
    dialog_my.dialog();
    $(".dialog",     dialog_my ).css('width','450px');


    }


);  


    });


</script>
```

But the line    `$(".dialog", dialog_my ).css('width','450px');` has no effect. If I omit the context and write the code as `$(".dialog" ).css('width','450px');` , then the css is applied both on the flat webpage and on the modal window.

How can I apply the  css only on the modal window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find a div with class `dialog` in `dialog_my` which **is** your div. Just put :

```
dialog_my.css('width','450px');
```

Or even better, with chaining methods:

```
dialog_my = $(".dialog").clone(false).dialog().css('width','450px');
```

Comment: please see my comment at papaiatis's reply

Comment: It is not working because jQuery tries to find a div with class `dialog` **inside** the div. The outmost div is not part of the DOM traversal.
As you can see on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DCYNk/), CSS is not applied to the div.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to give some width to the dialog, you can use this:

`dialog_my.dialog({width:450});`

Comment: @papaiatis, why won't the line with the context considered work? i think considering the context will work if the div is not the outmost div.

Comment: Because there is no element with class `dialog` in the object `dialog_my`. You can check it like this: `alert(dialog_my.html());`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI adds various classes to your DOM elements to make your `.dialog()`-call work. You can use this to style just the elements that you want.

With **css**:

```css
.ui-dialog {
  width: 450px;
}
```

Or **Javascript**:

```javascript
$('.ui-dialog').width(450);
```

The *Theming* tab of the official [plugin description](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) shows you more things you can modify.